# refresh page after jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, refresh

I am trying to refresh the page after a jQuery AJAX call. It appears that the page is refreshing (only sometimes) before all the data has been transmitted. Can anyone see why by this snippet below. I have the refresh code in the success function so I am confused.

I tried adding `async = false` and that didn't seem to work either.

```
function sendRating(rating, reload_on_return) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: window.url_root + cid + "/",
    data: {
        "rating": rating.r2 / 100.0
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
            console.log("data was sent!");

            if (reload_on_return) {
                    location.reload();

            }

        }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Data didn't get sent!!");
    }
})
```

Comment: why not just return the data you need to update on the page from your POST, or call a GET...Post Backs are just frustrating for a user.

Comment: Do you have any logs to show? What makes you say not all the data hasn't been transmitted?

Comment: This looks correct.  Is it possible other code is causing the refresh, or the refresh is in fact happening after the data returns?

Comment: How do you invoke sendRating? Is it on a form submit?

Comment: @Jonah The page is refreshing but then it is supposed to grab fresh data from the server, and that isn't always happening. (but it happens some time)

Comment: @pixelcdv Specifically, this data is being used to set `window.authenticated` and `window.score`. Sometimes `window.authenticated` isn't set and some times the `score` is 1 when it should be 2. This indicates to me that all the data wasn't transferred.

Comment: I think you need to cancel the form submit event. That's the reason it is reloading the page before the ajax request is complete.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could possibly do a setTimeout, to make it wait for a split second before the refresh can execute.

```
function sendRating(rating, reload_on_return) {

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    url: window.url_root + cid + "/",
    async: false,
    data: {
        "rating": rating.r2 / 100.0
    },
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty('success')) {
            console.log("data was sent!");

            if (reload_on_return) {
                setTimeout(
                  function() 
                  {
                     location.reload();
                  }, 0001);    
            }

        }
    },
    error: function() {
        console.log("Data didn't get sent!!");
    }
})
```

Comment: Is there anyway to call new function after refreshing page.